# "undefined reference to" Ros Cpp problem library

Tags: c++, ros

**Question**: I likely have a ROS Cpp library problem. My cpp is not linking to some of my hpp content. When it's just cpp, it works, when i add ros, it doesn't anymore. I'm not cpp fluent myself, what should i do to solve that?

**Error**:

```
 /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/node.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
    main.cpp:(.text+0x244): undefined reference to `A::A(int, char**)'
    /usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x258): undefined reference to `A::~A()'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Package config: I'm using Ros noetic

-->Ros_package

- include

  - A.hpp
  - all the h & hpp stuff
- src

  - main.cpp
  - all the c & cpp stuff

A.hpp content

```
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP


/*** I N C L U D E S **********************************************************/
#include QT/ another .hpp, another .h


/* D E F I N E S ************************************************************/
/* Debug helper */

/* S T R U C T U R E **********************************************************/
typedef struct stuff


/*** C L A S S ****************************************************************/
class A : public QThread
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    A (int argc, char** argv);
    virtual ~A (void);
    void run (void);

  private:
    method

  public slots:
    method

  private:
    stuff
};

#endif // A_HPP
```

Main.cpp content:

```
/* I N C L U D E S ************************************************************/
#include <QApplication>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <A.hpp>

/* M A I N ********************************************************************/
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  /* Launch main thread */
  ros::init(argc, argv, "test_dammit");

  A mainThread (argc, argv); 
  /*stuff

  return 0;
}
```

Cmakefile content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(ros_package)

catkin_package()

find_package(catkin REQUIRED roscpp)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Network REQUIRED)

include_directories(
 include
 ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
 ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)  

add_executable(node src/main.cpp )

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES} Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Network
)
```

**Context**: I'm adapting a non Ros cpp package to Ros. SO i know the hpp and cpp are correctly written. I Think I'm getting hpp/cpp library link troubles.

I can't seem to find a solution that works online. I tried many CmakeFile adaptation as well, no luck.

What should i look for?

Thank you all!

**EDit**:

This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) is pertinent if the code cpp doesn't work at all BUT the code WITHOUT ROS works perfectly. So the problem arises while doing Ros integration.

Answer (score 0):

This is technically a `CMake` and `catkin` issue rather than `ros` specifically. For catkin packages you have to call `catkin_package()` to generate catkin specific build information. This also must be called *before* `add_library` or `add_executable`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(ros_package)

catkin_package()

find_package(catkin REQUIRED roscpp)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Network REQUIRED)

include_directories(
 include
 ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
 ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)  

add_executable(node src/main.cpp )

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES} Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Network
)
```

For more info see [this wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#catkin_package.28.29).

Comment: BTables, Thank you, however i had wrongly erased lines while writing the question :/

Comment: sorry for this mistake